# Free webservice return list of countries and regions of this county and cities of this region

Tags: web-services

I'm doing webapp registration form and there  is address field which will be three drop down (Country - Region - City) I need to fill the three drop down with the data. so I need any free webservice that will return to me all the countries and when I ask it about the regions of each country will reply with this list and the cities about this region. or any suggestion about this situation will be good.

Thanks
Dohar

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not well defined. Not all countries have regions (what's the point of regions of Vatican City?), and you'll have to figure out whether Taiwan is a country - geopolitics is nasty.

Comment: okay if the county doesn't have regions the api inform me so I will ask about the cities of this country

Comment: Your tag is silly, please edit and give more precise tags. And you should indicate what is the point of your request. If that's to check validity of physical address, I will say that's pointless: there is probably no database complete enough and up to date for this information. (CIA database might be the closest of your need, perhaps.)

Answer (score 0):

This http://www.westclicks.com/web-services/ will atleast provide you with the list of countries and corresponding states. check if it can fullfill your requirement. But as mentioned by "MSalters" not all countries hav regions and if you want to populate the regions you should figure it out yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a broken link.